# How can i pass parameters to the constructors through the Service Container?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I have a class that is responseible for calling a 3rd party payment solution.

As a part of this, there are various merchant id/shared secret parameters.
Theses will depend on who's logged into the application.

The class I'm working with takes this info in the constructor when the class is built. Is there a way to pass this in the service provider, perhaps like this:

```
 $this->app->bind( 'App\BokaKanot\Interfaces\BillingInterface',function ($merchantId)
 {
    return new KlarnaBilling($merchantId);
 } );
```

If so, is it still possible to do this through a constructor or do I need to manaully use `App:make`. If I do have to use `App::make`, how can I not hide this inside my calling class?

Or should I refactor the class I'm using to not need this in the constructor, and perhaps have an init method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass parameters to `App::make` and pass the parameters to the constructor like this:

```php
$this->app->bind( 'App\BokaKanot\Interfaces\BillingInterface',
                   function( $app, array $parameters)
{
    //call the constructor passing the first element of $parameters
    return new KlarnaBilling( $parameters[0] );
} );

//pass the parameter to App::Make
App::make( 'App\BokaKanot\Interfaces\BillingInterface',  [ $merchantId ]  );
```

Comment: thanks for that! I can put the App:make in my controller, and then ask for an instance of it in a method below, but is there a way I can get and instance as a parameter in the constructor? If so where should I put the App:make? In the router.php?

Comment: @iKode : sorry but i don't understand your question. Could you make a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve by editing your question ?

Answer (score 5):

On laravel 5.4 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18271), you need to use the method makeWith of the IoC container.

```
App::makeWith( 'App\MyNameSpace\MyClass',  [ $id ]  );
```

if you still use 5.3 or below, the above answers will work

Comment: in Laravel 5.5, you can still use make('Class', $data), i think the method is back